# Global variable scope returns [Object object] instead of a string in node.js

Tags: android, node.js

I am trying to access the tokenName coming inside the request function which I am able to get in response successfully. But I want to access it globally so I can save it in database.

```
   request(options,function (error, response, body) {
    tokenName = body.notification_key; 
    console.log('tokenName: ' + tokenName); //I get the token name successfully
    return tokenName;
    });




        var data = {

                image: image,
                email: token_email,
                name: name1,
                notification_key: tokenName,   //now, here it returns [Object object],dont know why
                token_id: token_id1,
                extra: 'created'
                };
             console.log('image : ' + image);
             console.log('email : ' + token_email);
             console.log('name : ' + name1);
             console.log('tokenName : ' + tokenName);      //gives[Object object]
             console.log('token_id : ' + token_id1);

             return db.collection('Users').doc(user_id).set(data); //could not save because of this
```

the body of the JSON is like

```
{ notification_key: ‘WPX91bFxpiCMFe5p6JjypsOSgXn2lCVHMrX5Q1d-fjYqFoHMMc-
DjE8S97GJiCs0lw0DPGnckSGe_AQhhOViV5MF67Rodb9bNlCPmYt2UUi2-
vPmrwncYJs7NqdZE7DyuO3sZ0e_b98c’ }
```

[image]

I am not good in node.js.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

you should define 'tokenName' globally to use it outside the function and you should convert tokenName to string to save it in database like this :-

```
let tokenName; // i set this variable at global level


request(options,function (error, response, body) {

tokenName = body.notification_key; // asing the valeu to the global variable

console.log('tokenName: ' + tokenName); 

});




    var data = {

            image: image,
            email: token_email,
            name: name1,
            notification_key: tokenName,   //now it return token (string)
            token_id: token_id1,
            extra: 'created'
            };
         console.log('image : ' + image);
         console.log('email : ' + token_email);
         console.log('name : ' + name1);
         console.log('tokenName : ' + tokenName);      
         console.log('token_id : ' + token_id1);

         return db.collection('Users').doc(user_id).set(data);
```

Comment: its still coming to be the same. I've also observed that the data payload is running before the request function. u can check it as i am updating my post with an image.

Comment: i thing you should not return tokenName instead you set it globally and use directly so there will be no need to convert it into string